# What's a technical way to describe removed functionality in a software application or framework?

Tags: terminology

I'm not trained programmer, so be gentle with my ignorance.
I'm trying to search changelog files for where an open source project dropped a feature I need. I was just wondering if there may be a good set of terms to describe this.

Bugzilla has detailed bug reporting forms. Are design changes also logged using rigorous language?

Its something I can see myself advocating as my own small contribution. (^_^)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there's an explicit term for 'removed functionality'. Others have mentioned 'deprecated', but to my knowledge that means something is slated for removal at a later date and should be avoided.

Your best bet would be to use **Removed Functionality** or **Discontinued Feature**.

Comment: While deprecated is certainly a common reference to removal of something in software app., hierarchically its higher up from a _feature_ or _function_ where a missing user change may be referenced, so I'll accept this for the answer. and +1 to others...

Answer (score 2):

There are `two terms` that i am  currently recalling for functionality that will no longer be supported or used in .NET Framework next release(s):

a) **Obsolete** - The attribute Obsolete is used to mark types and members of types that should no longer be used. For more detailed info - [Obsolete (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22kk2b44%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

b) **Function is not supported** - Some Visual Basic 6.0 functions are [no longer supported in Visual Basic .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex2dtcee%28VS.71%29.aspx) . The functionality that these functions provided can be accomplished using new functions in the .NET Framework; however, the differences in implementation make it too difficult to upgrade automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the term is [deprecated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecated)

> **Deprecation** is a status applied to a computer software feature, characteristic, or practice indicating it should be avoided, typically because of it being superseded...
>
> While a deprecated software feature remains in the software its use may raise warning messages recommending alternative practices; deprecated status may also indicate that feature will be removed in the future. Features are deprecated rather than immediately removed to provide [backward compatibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_compatibility) and give programmers time to bring affected code into compliance with the new standard...

Comment: Deprecated specifically means that they are still there but are to be avoided because in future they may / will be removed. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation